# Android - Arduino Bluetooth communication

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

Hi Im new to android studio and java and was hoping to read data from arduino to android.

The plan is to have the button widget on my interface to send signal to the arduino and have my flex sensor send info back to the android via bluetooth.

the bluetooth module i have is HC-06 and this code is designed so that the phone sends a '*' to the arduino and it sends a random value back to the android but i would like that random value to be shown on a textbox on my interface. the change is meant to happen on java ofcourse but im not sure how to do it. Please help.

this is my arduino code first

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
const int RX_PIN = 2;
const int TX_PIN = 3;
SoftwareSerial serial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN);
char commandChar;

void setup ()
{
serial.begin (9600);
andomSeed(analogRead(0))
}

void loop ()
{
 if(serial.available())
 {
  commandChar = serial.read();
 switch(commandChar)
  {
      case '*':
      serial.print(random(1000) + "#");
      break;
     }
  }
}
```

and here is my code done on android studio:

```
package com.example.ft.myapplication;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
// Device does not support Bluetooth
    }
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new                    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
    }
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices =   mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    BluetoothDevice mDevice = null;
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            mDevice = device;
        }
    }
    ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
    mConnectThread.start();


}

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
        int end = (int)msg.arg2;

        switch(msg.what) {
           case 1:
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
    public void run() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }
        ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }
    public void run() {
        String s = "*";
        write(s.getBytes());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int begin = 0;
        int bytes = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
                for(int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
                    if(buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                        begin = i + 1;
                        if(i == bytes - 1) {
                            bytes = 0;
                            begin = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

}